# MaskedTextBox inside KendoGrid

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, mvc-editor-templates, maskedtextbox

Is it possible to use the Kendo MaskedTextBox inside a Kendo Grid? If so, how?

I am using an Editor template for the MaskedTextBox.

```
@model object

@Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(m => m).Mask("(000) 000-0000")
```

The Kendo Grid has a telephone field that uses the MaskedTextBox, but it doesn't grab the mask.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(new ContactViewModel[] { })
        .Name("ServiceLocationContactsGrid")
        .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.ForeignKey(c => c.ContactTypeId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["contactTypes"], "ContactTypeId", "Description").EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey");
            column.Bound(c => c.LastName).Width(700);
            column.Bound(c => c.FirstName);
            column.Bound(c => c.Title);
            column.Bound(c => c.EmailAddress);
            column.Bound(c => c.TelephoneNumber).EditorTemplateName("Telephone");
            column.Bound(c => c.TelephoneExtension);
            column.Bound(c => c.FaxNumber).EditorTemplateName("String");
            column.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text(" ").UpdateText(" ").CancelText(" "); command.Destroy().Text(" "); }).Width(180).Visible(!ViewBag.ReadOnlyView);
        })
            .ToolBar(toolBar =>
            {
                if(!ViewBag.ReadOnlyView) toolBar.Create().Text("Add New Contact");
            })
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
            dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(c => c.ContactId);
                model.Field(c => c.ContactId).Editable(false);
            })
            .Create(create => create.Action("CreateContact", "Contact"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateContact", "Contact"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("ListContacts", "Contact"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("DestroyContact", "Contact"))
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after making editor template, you should put it on the cell you want.
Editor Template

@(Html.kendo().MaskedTextBoxFor(m=>m).Name("test").mask("00/00/000"))

then you should put your editor template in grid:

```
columns.Bound(x=>x.test).EditorTemplateName("Test");
```

this code worked for me

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score -1):

You could set the ui hint of the properties you want to use with the editor template e.g.

[UIHint("your template here")]

Public string YourMaskedProperty { get;set;}

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work.                 `[UIHint("Telephone")]
 public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }`

Comment: I take it your editor template is in a folder called EditorTemplates either with the view this belongs to or the shared views folder.

Comment: Yes, the Telephone template is in the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder.